# IBM MobileFirst. Cannot create .wlapp with extended authenticity enabled

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Im trying to configure extended authenticity for cordova-based hybrid app.
`mfp version is 7.1.0.00.20151227-1730`

- Built signed release .apk
- Built .wlapp
- `wladm> enable extended-authenticity r.wlapp r.apk > extended.wlapp`

Output:
`Analyzing executable file.
Generating new .wlapp file...
invalid entry compressed size (expected 11444 but got 11433 bytes)`

Tried with unsigned .apk
The output was that unsigned .apk is unsupported.

How to properly create .wlapp with extended authenticity enabled?

Comment: Did you create the application in one OS but used the wladm tool in another OS? (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `invalid entry compressed size (expected 11444 but got 11433 bytes)` means that the wladm program could not find a valid ZIP file structure in one of the two files (the .wlapp or .apk file).

There are two possible causes of this error:

- A transmission error from the machine on which the file was created to the machine where you run wladm. Examples of such transmission errors are a transfer with FTP in text mode, or a commit in text mode in a source code management system, but there may be more. You can determine whether there was a transmission error by taking a hash code (say, sha1sum) of the file where it was created and where it is being consumed by wladm, and comparing these hash codes. Do this for both the .wlapp and the .apk files.
- It could also be that the file uses some extensions of the ZIP file format (such as ZIP64) that wladm does not understand. In this case, try to use wladm with a newer Java (that is, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to a Java 7 or Java 8 implementation).

If neither of these hints helps, this is a case for the IBM MobileFirst support. Please open a ticket with them, and submit both of the files. They will treat both files confidentially.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that the original .wlapp file uses a slightly different compression algorithm than the new .wlapp file that the "enable extended-authenticity" command wants to create.

The workaround is to unzip and re-jar the .wlapp file before attempting the "enable extended-authenticity" operation:

```
$ mkdir tmpdir
$ cd tmpdir
$ unzip -x ../r.wlapp
$ rm -f ../r.wlapp
$ jar cf ../r.wlapp *
$ cd ..
```